# Cannot find type 'OSHandleNotificationReceivedBlock' in scope

Tags: ios, swift

I'm unable to solve the issue

```
  let notificationReceivedBlock: OSHandleNotificationReceivedBlock = { notification in

        print("Received Notification: \(notification!.payload.notificationID)")
    }
```

Comment: Did you `import` the third party framework this API belongs to?

Comment: I have added OneSignalXCFramework(under package dependencies )

Comment: That's not enough. You have to `import OneSignalXCFramework` in the class – or whatever the actual name is.

Comment: yeah..I have imported # import OneSignal in the file